# The KeyDown event of a Simple style combo box is raised two times

Tags: winforms, combobox, keydown

I have simple win form application with  the tab and combo box controls.

- Combo box control has a style of "Simple".
- Tab control has key down event.

When I press Enter key on the combo control it fires **TWO** key down events. If you change the combo style to any other, the key down event fires only one which it is something I expect.

Has anybody got any ideas why I am getting two key down events for single enter key press?
I have found similar issue on the Microsoft website, but that was related to .NET 1.0.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814970

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has probably something to do with the Enter key having pre-defined behavior for the Simple DropDown style.

You can try this work-around in the KeyDown event:

```
void comboBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
  e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
  // do stuff
}
```

As you can guess, the KeyPress event won't fire now.

If you need to still process things in the KeyPress event, you can try this work-around:

```
void comboBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
  if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter) {
    e.Handled = true;
  } else {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I wll give it a try tommorow. Just wondering if it is .net bug?

Answer (score 0):

KeyPress from Combobox accepts just 'char' keys. For you purpose, please, use KeyDown event for combobox and e.Handled property.

Then your code will work and look like:

```
private void comboBox2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                comboBox2.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(comboBox2_SelectionChangeCommitted);
            }

            if (e.KeyCode != Keys.Enter)
            {

                e.Handled = false;

            }
        }
```